# cant list to port 80 on apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, port

i want to access my localhost on port 80,

#### all the ports are working except the port 80

i used netstate in order to know who is using the port 80 and i found the port 80 in this way:

Proto Local Address
TCP 0.0.0.0.80

what should i do please?

i need to listen to port 80 because i want my localhost call without the port number so the portnumber will be the default witch is 80

Comment: Just from experience.. is your Skype turned on? Because Skype uses port 80 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try a netstat -a -n -o and find the PID of that process that is using port 80 then type in the following command to know which application is using that process

tasklist /svc /FI "PID eq 5988"

Here 5988 is the PID.

Once you get to know which application is using that port simply terminate it.